# Salesforce Lead Capture 'Lead Record Type' is being recorded incorrectly

Tags: record-type

When leads are being pulled into the salesforce account from facebook using Lead Capture the 'Lead Record Type' is being recorded incorrectly.

There's a picklist with 2 options, but it defaults to the wrong option.

Is there a way to ensure the Lead Record Type is correctly assigned when being brought in?

Thanks.

Comment: how the lead is being capture from facebook ??

Comment: Via Salesforce Lead Capture
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DrzmfUAB

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the default record type assigning check for Lead object like below : -

To specify record types and page layout assignments:

1. From Setup, enter Profiles in the Quick Find box,
2. Select a profile.
3. In the Find Settings... box, enter the
   name of the object (In your case it will be lead) you want and select it from the list. Click Edit.
4. edit the record type settings and make the record type default which you want to set. please find the screenshot below : -

[image]

by this way you can set the default record type.

Comment: Hi Avijit, 

Thanks for all your help so far, much appreciated.

Could you elaborate on "In the Find Settings... box"  I cant seem to make it to the screenshot shown in page 4.

Just to clarify i am not using Lightning Experience if this is assumed.

Comment: go to setup and in the left panel in the search box you an type that.

Comment: is it working??